# Mongo upsert not working on created_at and updated_at

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have JSON data and want to save in the database in such a way if userId is not present then is inserted otherwise update.
But here is a twist in which document is not found created_at and updated_at will also save with current date format. If the document is found so updated_at will also save.

```
{
  "userId": "12",
  "name": "abc",
  "mob": "34341111"
}
```

I tried but not worked well.

```
db.info.upsert({'userId': 12}, {$set: {"userId": "12", "name": "abc", "mob": "34341"}}, function(err, data){})
```

schema is defined as.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: String, required: true},
  userId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true},
  name: {type: Date, required: false},
  mob: {type: String, required: false},
  created_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: new Date()},
  updated_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: new Date()},
});
```

We have another approach first have to check data is present or not then according update the data, but we have to use in a single query. Please tell me how to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using mongoose `.findOneAndUpdate()`, If data is found based on condition it will update otherwise add the data to DB.

```
db.info.findOneAndUpdate({'userId': 12},{$set:{"userId": "12", "name": "abc", "mob":"34341"}},{upsert:true,setDefaultsOnInsert:true},function(err,data){})
```

Using two flags `upsert:true` and `setDefaultsOnInsert:true` these will upsert the data if doesnt exist and set defaults while inserting.

You can read more on [findOneAndUpdate here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: Can we do by upsert command instead of findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I have never seen a upsert command before, am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, the Interviewer asked about this situation, how to handle when using upsert command

Comment: I think that's what he meant as there is no `upsert` command by itself, so by his questions he meant `how to handle update when using usert with it`?